WOULD - Typical behavior in the present tense? - LONGMAN
From Longman Dictionary of Contemporary English:
"11 TYPICAL BEHAVIOUR spoken used to say that an action is typical or expected – usually used to show disapproval

You would go and spoil it, wouldn’t you?
She insists that she did nothing wrong, but then she would say that, wouldn’t she?"

Do we use would for Typical behavior in the present tense as the above explanation describes?
Also, tell me what 'disapproval' really means here.
Edit :  "From Oxford Learner's Dictionaries:
(usually disapproving) used for talking about behaviour that you think is typical. 

‘She said it was your fault.’ ‘Well, she would say that, wouldn't she? She's never liked me.’"


"Well he would, wouldn't he?" - commonly referred to as Mandy Rice-Davies Applies (shortened to MRDA), is a British political phrase and aphorism that is commonly used as a retort to a self-interested denial. But I'm not sure "typical behaviour" accurately paraphrases the usage, because it can apply in a context where the subject has never done / said whatever. It means that's what we would expect him to do / say (even if he's never done it before, you can extrapolate from what you know of earlier behaviour).

...in the actual original MRDA, I think the only reason we "expected" the relevant public figure to deny having had an affair with Mandy Rice-Davies was because people don't like their private sexual activities to be aired in public. It wasn't because Lord Astor was famous for habitually denying sexual "indiscretions" at the time.

Why not just accept what those dictionaries say? Why are you saying present tense? Those explanations don't say present tense, do they? They would, wouldn't they if it were. There is always an if lurking behind the use of would when it's not a past tense of will. and the use of "X would, wouldn't they? is not British per se at all. It's used all the time in all variants of English. Also used are other modals and auxiliaries for action verbs: Person 1: He always follows the rules. Person 2: Well he should, shouldn't he? Or: Well, he will, won't he? etc. etc. etc.

Where are you getting "in the present tense"?  The example utterances  using would are not in the present tense. Are you referring to the dictionary's phrase "is typical"?  Typical behavior is timeless.  You can expect that it will happen, is happening, and has always happened.

This use of would is something you say with annoyance when something bad happens or someone does something you don't like.

It would rain just when we were planning to go for a walk!

(You feel it is 'typical of your bad luck' just because you are annoyed that the weather has spoiled your plans.)

You would go and spoil it, wouldn't you?

(You are annoyed by the person's behaviour so you unkindly suggest that it is 'typical' of them to behave like that - whether or not it really is.)

Yes, also used to express annoyance, right.
